# PHP reindex array method

Tags: php, arrays

I have:

```
foreach($filters as $key => $filter) {
        $filters[$filter['field']] = [
            'operator' => $filter['operator'],
            'value' => $filter['value']
        ];
        unset($filters[$key]);
    }
```

Which works great, but I am left wondering if there is a short version or built in function that does the same?

Comment: if there is - I think this is the fastest way.

Comment: Well, you can get rid of manual looping with array_map(), I guess

Comment: Have you thought about what would happen if $filter['field'] is identical to $key ?
Modifying the array that you're currently looping over seems dangerous. Depending on your requirements, there's a good chance you want to write to a temporary array, before resetting $filters

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) together with [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$result = array_combine(
    array_column($filters, 'field'),
    $filters
);
```

This will leave `'field'` elements inside an array. If you want to remove it you can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$result = array_combine(
    array_column($filters, 'field'),
    array_map(function ($filter) {
        return [
            'operator' => $filter['operator'],
            'value' => $filter['value']
        ];
    }, $filters)
);
```

For the sake of simplicity I accessed keys directly, but in production you should always check whether this key is present inside the array.